# falha em trecho de função para ler tabela

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Estou desenvolvendo uma função que ler duma tabela e insere na outra:

O erro é: Advertência: Função criada com erros de compilação.

Eu retirei a linha do select e funciona. Entõa, o erro é nela.

```
create or replace function FC_INS_TIPO_GASTO  
return number  
as  

  v_numSubCota transparencia_gastos.numSubCota%type;  
  v_txtDescricao transparencia_gastos.txtDescricao%type;  

begin  
  select distinct numSubCota into v_numSubCota, txtDescricao into 

  v_txtDescricao
  from transparencia_gastos
  where sgUF='PB' or sgUF='PE'; 



  insert into tipo_gasto
  (cod_tipo_gasto, des_tipo_gasto, dtc_cadastro)
  values
  (v_numSubCota, v_txtDescricao, systimestamp);



  return 0;  
end;  
/
```

Será que não pode fazer select dentor de begin end? Mas eu já testei fora do bloco e não funciona também.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi usando cursor.

```
create or replace function FC_INS_TIPO_GASTO return number as

  cursor c_transparencia_gastos is
    select distinct numSubCota, txtDescricao
      from transparencia_gastos
     where sgUF = 'PB'
        or sgUF = 'PE';

begin
  for rg in c_transparencia_gastos loop
    insert into tipo_gasto
      (cod_tipo_gasto, des_tipo_gasto, dtc_cadastro)
    values
      (rg.numSubCota, rg.txtDescricao, systimestamp);

  end loop;

  return 0;
end;
```

É claro que coloquei tratamento de erros e o retorno não é apenas, 0, depende do erro, mas como a pergunta só foi sobre o select, só coloquei a resposta principal.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possível fazer operações dml sem problema dentro deu m bloco plsql, o problema esta na sintaxe do seu select, você usou duas vezes a cláusula into dentro da mesma consulta. o Correto seria

```
select distinct numSubCota, txtDescricao
  into v_numSubCota, v_txtDescricao
  from transparencia_gastos
 where sgUF = 'PB'
    or sgUF = 'PE';
```

Lembrando que a operação "select into" só permite o retorno de um registro de cada vez. No seu código como contem uma condição OR no filtro, da a impressão que pode retornar mais de um registro.

No seu caso, conforme você já respondeu, seria melhor fazer um loop fazendo o insert. Porém outra opção seria utilizar um "insert select" assim realizando tudo em uma só operação e otimizando a performance.

```
insert into tipo_gasto
  (cod_tipo_gasto, des_tipo_gasto, dtc_cadastro)
  select distinct numSubCota, txtDescricao, systimestamp
    from transparencia_gastos
   where sgUF = 'PB'
      or sgUF = 'PE';
```